# calling a method with multiple default values

Tags: c#, methods

i was wondering, because i have a method with multiple default parameters

```
private string reqLabel(string label, byte fontSize = 10, string fontColour = "#000000", string fontFamily = "Verdana"  )
{
   return "<br /><strong><span style=\"font-family: " + fontFamily + ",sans-serif; font-size:" +fontSize.ToString() + "px; color:"+ fontColour + "; \">" + label +" : </span></strong>";
}
```

and when i call the method it i have to do it in order

```
reqLabel("prerequitie(s)")
reqLabel("prerequitie(s)", 12) 
reqLabel("prerequitie(s)", 12 , "blue")
reqLabel("prerequitie(s)", 12 , "blue", "Tahoma")
```

so my question is, is there any way to skip the first few default parameters?

Let's say i want to input only the colour, and the font-family like this:

```
reqLabel("Prerequisite(s)" , "blue" , "Tahoma") 

/* or the same with 2 comma's where the size param is supposed to be. */

reqLabel("Prerequisite(s)" ,  , "blue" , "Tahoma")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with explicit naming:

```
reqLabel("Prerequisite(s)" , fontColour: "blue", fontFamily: "Tahoma")
```

Just note that named arguments should always be the last ones - you cannot specify positioned arguments after named. In other words, this is not allowed:

```
reqLabel("Prerequisite(s)" , fontColour: "blue", "Tahoma")
```

Comment: @Alberto, Adam, thanks for pointing out the syntax problem. Always tend to confuse syntax for this and anonymous objects, maybe because I use the the latter way more often.

Answer (score 4):

Use [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
reqLabel("prerequitie(s)", fontSize: 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call with name parameters:

```
reqLabel("Prerequisite(s)" , fontColour: "blue" , fontFamily: "Tahoma")
```